# Allocate a child resource to two different parents resources (?)

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

I have a articles blog like so:

**(parent) Category: News

(child) article: news-1 written by author-tom

(child) article: news-2 written by author-bill**

**(parent) Category: Sports

(child) article: sports-4 written by author-bill

(child) article: sports-7 written by author-jack**

**(parent) Category: Weather

(child) article: weather-1 written by author-tom

(child) article: weather-3 written by author-jack**

Author name is a template_variable. And for each article I input the author name manually.

The author names are clickable links. And what I want to achieve is that when a user clicks "author-bill", for example, that the user only sees ALL articles written by "author-bill", thus articles news-2 and sports-4. For "author-jack" the same (sports-7 and weather-3).

I cannot allocate a child to two different parents (i.e. to both the "news" category AND to "author-jack" for example...).

I am stuck in thinking about a feasible solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getResources to search all your categories for the author name template variable. You don't need to assign multiple parents [though if you insisted on doing that you could use a resource alias to fake it]

Your getResources would look something like:

```
[[!getResources?
     &parents=`1,2,3` // your category ids
     &tvFilters=`author_name==[[+author_name]]` //pass the author in a placeholder

etc.
```

Read the docs: http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources

Comment: Thanks. I use MODx EVO so I would need to work with Ditto instead to implement your idea. Can I implement your proposal with Ditto too?